# How to add vertices at run time in ruby by using Ruby Graph Library?

Tags: ruby, ruby-rgl

I used the following code to create a graph.

How to +add vertices at the run time?

```
require 'rgl/adjacency'
dg = RGL::DirectedAdjacencyGraph[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
dg.edges
```

Comment: This can't be that simple. Am I missing something here??

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use

```
dg.add_vertex 8
```

Check it with

```
dg.vertices
```

But if you want to see the vertex in edges you need to link it with another vertex
You need to do this.

```
dg.add_edge(7,8)
```

**In your case graph is sort of unbalanced.**

After initialization, this is what you get

```
[(1-2), (3-4), (5-6), (7-)]
```

All the adjacent vertex pair up to form an edge.

Where vertex 7 forms an edge with nil.

Remove it with

```
dg.remove_edge(7,nil)
```

Please read the [manual](http://rgl.rubyforge.org/rgl/classes/RGL/DirectedAdjacencyGraph.html)